# Can't publish iOS app - Not supported version (SDK → Xcode → OS)

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I bought a 2011 Mac just to publish an iOS app to the App Store. But, it turns out that I can't publish using the currently installed OS. Is there anything I can do to fix it?

I execute Xcode → Product → Archive, then **upload to store** and get the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90725: "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later. Further, starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later."
>   An unknown error occurred.

So I downloaded Xcode 10.1 but it's not supported with my OS.

> Xcode can’t be installed on “1111” because macOS version 10.14.3 or later is required.

So I download macOS Mojave 10.14.3, but when trying to install it, I get the following error:

> This software is not supported on your system.

Please tell me there is a simple solution for this. It doesn't make sense that if you have an old computer you can't publish iOS apps anymore.

I have a Early 2011 15" MacBook Pro.

Comment: You don't say exactly which Mac you have, but unless you have an upgraded Mac Pro you need a mid 2012 or newer Mac to install 10.14 - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave.  Unfortunately it isn't possible to publish iOS apps with the Mac you have.

Comment: "It doesn't make sense that if you have an old computer you can't publish apps enymore (sic)" Unfortunately, this is your opinion. Research into the topic would have shown you that [any system prior to mid-2012 isn't compatible with Mojave (10.14)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201475).

Comment: Sorry, no.  You might want to look into a "Mac in the cloud" provider; you can develop in Swift 4 using your Mac and use the cloud service to build the release and upload it. Not ideal, but the best you can do short of buying a newer Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 10.1 works with macOS 10.13.x (where x is 4 or 5 I think). Your 2011 MacBook Pro can run macOS 10.13. Once you have macOS 10.13.x (where x is whatever the latest version is), you can use Xcode 10.1 and you can then build and submit your app to the App Store.

Keep in mind that this setup may only be good for another year depending on when Apple requires apps to be built with Xcode 10.2 or later which will require macOS 10.14 or later which your 2011 MacBook Pro doesn't support.

> It doesn't make sense that if you have an old computer you can't publish apps anymore.

Yes, it does make sense. Apple likes to have everyone keep current. They sell software and hardware. They want you buying up-to-date hardware and using up-to-date tools. They want you keeping your apps up-to-date to take advantage of new features. This benefits the end user which should be your primary focus.